# imprimindo lixo de memória

Tags: c, string, memória

Este programa deve carregar palavras de um arquivo `txt` para um vetor, 
sortear 10 palavras, coloca-las em vetor e depois imprimir na tela. 
O problema é que está imprimindo lixo de memória e não sei como resolver este problema.

Como resolver o problema?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct
{    
    char VetorFacil[20];    
} VETORES;

void carregaPalavrasFacil(VETORES *vetorFuncFacil);
void mostraPalavrasFacil();
void pontuacao();

void main()
{

    int op, i;
    VETORES vetorFuncFacil[10] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};

    printf("Escolha o nivel em que deseja jogar: \n");
    puts("1) Facil");
    puts("2) Medio");
    puts("3) Dificil");
    puts("4) Ajuda");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%i", &op);

    switch (op)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            carregaPalavrasFacil(vetorFuncFacil);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            printf("Sim\n");
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            printf("Sim\n");
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            puts("Ajuda!");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            puts("Opção Inválida!");
            break;
        }
    }
}

void carregaPalavrasFacil(VETORES *vetorFuncFacil)
{

    int i, cont = 0, pegalinha, para;
    char line[20];
    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen("facil.txt", "r");
    if (arquivo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Arquivo Inválido!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        for (cont = 0; cont < 20; cont++)
        {
            int numero = rand() % 20;
            do
            {
                if (pegalinha == numero)
                {
                    fgets(line, sizeof(line), arquivo);
                    strcpy((*vetorFuncFacil).VetorFacil, line);
                    para = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    pegalinha++;
                }
            } while (para != 1);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", vetorFuncFacil[i].VetorFacil);
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
}
```

Aqui está o arquivo com as palavras para não dar erro de arquivo inválido: https://pastebin.com/w65SnD4Q

Comment: Tente usar o `free()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um programa capaz de atender o enunciado do problema de maneira bem clara e eficiente utilizando alocacação dinâmica de memória.

Repare que cada função é responsável por uma parte da tarefa e possuem nomes bem sugestivos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


#define ARQ_LISTA_PALAVRAS        "facil.txt"
#define LINHA_MAX_TAM             (100)
#define QTD_PALAVRAS_SORTEADAS    (10)


typedef struct lista_palavras_s
{
    char ** palavras;
    int cont;
} lista_palavras_t;


lista_palavras_t * carregar_lista_palavras( const char * arq )
{
    char linha[ LINHA_MAX_TAM + 1 ] = {0};
    int n = 0;
    FILE * pf = NULL;
    lista_palavras_t * lst = NULL;

    pf = fopen( arq, "r");

    if( !pf )
        return NULL;

    lst = (lista_palavras_t*) calloc( 1, sizeof(lista_palavras_t) );

    while( fgets( linha, LINHA_MAX_TAM, pf ) )
    {
        linha[strcspn(linha, "\n")] = 0;
        linha[strcspn(linha, "\r")] = 0;

        n++;

        lst->palavras = (char**) realloc( lst->palavras, sizeof(char*) * n );

        lst->palavras[n-1] = (char*) calloc( strlen(linha) + 1, sizeof(char) );

        strcpy( lst->palavras[n-1], linha );
    }

    fclose(pf);

    lst->cont = n;

    return lst;
}


lista_palavras_t * sortear_palavras( lista_palavras_t * lst, int qtd )
{
    int i = 0;
    lista_palavras_t * sort = NULL;

    sort = (lista_palavras_t*) calloc( 1, sizeof(lista_palavras_t) );

    sort->palavras = (char**) calloc( qtd, sizeof(char*) );

    for( i = 0; i < qtd; i++ )
        sort->palavras[i] = strdup( lst->palavras[ rand() % lst->cont ] );

    sort->cont = qtd;

    return sort;
}


void exibir_lista_palavras( lista_palavras_t * lst )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < lst->cont; i++ )
        fprintf( stdout, "%d - %s\n", i + 1, lst->palavras[i] );
}


void liberar_lista_palavras( lista_palavras_t * lst )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < lst->cont; i++ )
        free(lst->palavras[i]);

    free(lst->palavras);

    free(lst);
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    lista_palavras_t * lst = NULL;
    lista_palavras_t * sort = NULL;

    srand(time(NULL));

    lst = carregar_lista_palavras( ARQ_LISTA_PALAVRAS );

    if( !lst )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Erro ao carregar arquivo: %s\n", ARQ_LISTA_PALAVRAS );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    sort = sortear_palavras( lst, QTD_PALAVRAS_SORTEADAS );

    exibir_lista_palavras( sort );

    liberar_lista_palavras( lst );
    liberar_lista_palavras( sort );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Teste #1:

```
1 - informal
2 - endógeno
3 - cumprido
4 - conflito
5 - moderado
6 - presente
7 - proceder
8 - plenária
9 - patético
10 - angariar
```

Teste #2:

```
1 - preterir
2 - mediante
3 - informal
4 - sarcasmo
5 - arguição
6 - sinônimo
7 - perfazer
8 - hediondo
9 - fortuito
10 - apetecer
```

Comment: Blz valeu a ajuda vou dar uma estudada no programa e agora reimplementar ele em C++...